# load json language files dynamically

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am using react-native-localization like this:

```
import LocalizedStrings from 'react-native-localization';
import en_US from '../assets/i18n/en_US';
import en_UK from '../assets/i18n/en_UK';
import config from '../config/config';

const languages = {en_US, en_UK};
const translations = new LocalizedStrings(languages);
```

is it possible to load them based on config. In config:

```
   {
     enabledLanguages : ["en_UK"],

   }
```

So at any given time, there could be multiple language files in the app but not all of them will be enabled. Is there a way to load them up dynamically based on the enabledLanguages key of the configuration file?

I have seen

Comment: Did you got any solution?

Comment: Did you got any solution?